# What does "The minification process creates a file that is optimized for browsers to read and process" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> These rules encourage liberal spacing for improved developer readability. The minification process creates a file that is optimized for browsers to read and process.

Comment: You're encouraged to use plenty of whitespace and semantic indenting when writing code (Javascript, CSS, perhaps HTML), but "minification" removes all unnecessary spaces, tabs, and line breaks and renames some variables to have shorter names - it's more about producing a smaller file for faster transmission over the network than about the way the Web browser processes it.

Comment: Which words or phrase specifically? You can find the meaning of "minification" by Google search or in Wikipedia.

Comment: @user3169 I know the meaning of every word, but I can't understand the whole sentence. Now I know. Thank you.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think you've nailed it in that comment. I was going to put an answer up but it would only be pretty much what you've said there. Would you consider converting your comment otherwise I can see this becoming another 'unanswered' question

Comment: I agree, it should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're use plenty of white space and semantic indenting when writing code (Javascript, CSS, or HTML). Behind the scenes, the additional white space is automatically removed (since the computer does not need it) in a process call "minification".

> The minification process creates a file that is optimized for browsers to read and process.

The above sentence means:
The mification process removed additional white space, so created a new file base of your original code file, this file is optimized for browsers to read and process.